# GLEW functions can't be found

Tags: c++, opengl, glew, glfw

I am on Ubuntu, writing an application using OpenGL, GLEW and GLFW. I am using Eclipse as my IDE, and am having problems when trying to use functions such as **glGenRenderbuffer**. I have a very similar structure set up under Windows but can't get it to work on Linux.

I am linking to the libraries *glfw* and *GLEW*. I am able to compile and run parts of my application and can initialize both GLFW and GLEW. From these test runs I learn the following:

```
OpenGL version: 4.2.0 NVIDIA 304.64
Using GLEW 1.6.0
```

However, I can't get the function **glGenRenderbuffer** (or other framebuffer functions) to compile. I have tried adding both EXT and ARB to the name, as well as playing around with glex.h without any luck. As far as I know, the purpose of GLEW is to handle all extension issues, right?

The source file (*VolumeRenderer.cpp*) includes are done like this:

```
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <VolumeRenderer.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>
```

Further down, I am trying to use the function like this (only partially complete function, of course):

```
bool VolumeRenderer::InitFramebuffers()
{
  glGenRenderbuffers(1, &renderBufferObject_);
  return true;
}
```

All I get is **"function 'glGenRenderBuffers' could not be resolved".**

Looking in the GL/glew.h header I am including, I found the following lines among others:

```
#define glGenRenderbuffers GLEW_GET_FUN(__glewGenRenderbuffers)
#define glGenRenderbuffersEXT GLEW_GET_FUN(__glewGenRenderbuffersEXT)
```

But the compiler still can't find the function. Is there anything I have forgotten, or maybe some tests and checks I can run to see what is happening?

Comment: It would help us, if you included the error messages output by the build process.

Comment: GLEW should always be included first. Preferably before any user headers like this `VolumeRenderer` which could be including anything.

Comment: Are you checking either the OpenGL version (e.g., `GLEW_VERSION_3_2`) or the extension variables that GLEW provides (e.g,. `GLEW_EXT_framebuffer_object`)?  Those will tell you if the driver that GLEW's talking to has the features you're looking for.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Good point. It did not change anything this time, however.

Comment: @datenwolf: The only message I see is "Function 'glGenRenderbuffers' could not be resolved". I have not been using Eclipse a lot before though, so let me know if I should look elsewhere!

Comment: @radical7: I check the OpenGL version with glGetString(GL_VERSION), and it gives me "4.2.0" back. When I try to use GLEW_EXT_framebuffer_object, that symbol can't be resolved either. I tried to put it right after the call to glewInit() too, but the same problem occurs.

Comment: @VictorSand: A symbol that can't be resolved means that the symbol can't be found in the library. As Nicol Bolas already mentioned you should include glew.h before everything else. That is because is uses preprocessor macros to rewrite function names into the names found in the GLEW library. Without those, the symbols will remain unaltered and you get the error you observe.

Comment: @datenwolf: I tried moving includes around, and also stripping everything external like GLM. No success. However, I did manage to get everything to work by simply starting over. See answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so I got it to work by basically copying my Eclipse project file by file into a new, empty project. However, I did some other things before that. First, I moved around the includes as suggested in the helpful comments. I also removed things like glm. No success! Then I made a simple project in Eclipse with one single .cpp file, and linked to glfw and GLEW:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
  if (glfwInit() != GL_TRUE) {
    std::cout << "glfwInit() failed\n";
    exit(1);
  }
  if (!glfwOpenWindow(800, 600, 8 , 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, GLFW_WINDOW)) {
    std::cout << "glfwOpenWindow() failed\n";
    exit(1);
  }
  char *glVersion = (char*)glGetString(GL_VERSION);
  if (glVersion) {
    std::cout << "OpenGL version: " << glVersion << "\n";
  }
  GLenum err = glewInit();
  if (err != GLEW_OK) {
    std::cout << "GLEW init failed: " << glewGetErrorString(err) << "\n";
    exit(1);
  } else {
    std::cout << "Using GLEW " << glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION) << "\n";
  }
  GLuint buf;
  glGenRenderbuffers(1, &buf);
  exit(0);
}
```

That worked like a charm. I then tried to recreate my old problem by making another project with a similar file and include structure, and it seemed to work fine too. I then started a third, empty project where I simply made exact copies of the files that were originally giving me trouble. Now I have an exact copy of the original project (that now had the include order changed) with the exact same libraries linked to it, and it works. I still don't know what happened but I suspect that my project in Eclipse got messed up somehow, and never recovered even though I made some changes.